# Rounding to the nearest number ending in 9

Tags: c#, rounding

I have a website that calculates the price of bus tickets. Currently the price is rounded to the nearest 10, but now I want the calculated price to be rounded to the nearest number ending in 9.

**EDIT:** Added new examples answering question from the comments.

Examples:

- 770 to 774 should be rounded to 769
- 775 to 784 should be rounded to 779
- 785 to 790 should be rounded to 789

Does anybody have any tips on how I can solve my problem using c#?

Comment: ...round to the nearest 10 and subtract 1? Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Round to the nearest 10 and then subtract 1.

In c#, you can do it like this :

```
double val = 444.3;

double step1 = val/10;                 // 44.43
double step2 = Math.Round(step1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 44
int step3 = (int)step2 * 10;           // 440
int rndVal = step3 - 1;                // rndVal == 439
```

or the shortest version :

```
double val = 444.3;
int rndVal = (int)(Math.Round(val/10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)*10)-1;
```

Comment: to drag-and-drop, thanks for the MidpointRounding parameter, it works. Thanks to @paulf too for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add 1, round to nearest 10 and then subtract 1.

Answer (score 0):

The function below will do the job.

```
public static int RoundTo9(double value) 
{
    return (int)(value/10.0  + 0.5) * 10 - 1;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this answer?  is it not working or is it complex? Please explain before downvote.

Answer (score -1):

```
int number=65;
       // Console.WriteLine(number);
        int lastNumber=number%10;
        //Console.WriteLine(lastNumber);
        if(lastNumber<5)
        {
            number-=lastNumber;
            number--;
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
        else
        {
            var addNumber=10-lastNumber;
            number+=addNumber;
            number--;
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
```